# Delete a folder named '~'

Tags: linux, bash

I've been a fool.

I've written a python script that's supposed to create a folder at `~/photos` and then write some files to it. However, instead of this it created a folder in my working directory called `'~'`. (including the `'`s).

I foolishly stormed ahead with an `rm -rf ~` and hit enter before thinking. After spending the last few hours recovering I've ran the python script again and once again I'm faced with a folder named `'~'`.

Too terrified to run any command to remove it, I've come here to ask: How do I delete this folder safely? Am I safe to run `rm -r '~'`? (with the `'`s)

Comment: If you feel unsure, you can always run `ls '~'` before `rm -r '~'` to double-check.

Comment: See also [Does ~ always equal $HOME](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/146671)

Comment: @Wieland `ls '~'` was the solution for me here. Thanks for this.

Comment: If you are unsure and you even are not sure if `ls` and `rm` work the same way, I would have renamed `~` using `mv ./~ baddir` (`./~` should not be interpreted as the home directory) and then check if the bad directory has been renamed to `baddir`. In the worst case, your home directory is renamed to `baddir`. In the good case, you can safely do a `rm -r baddir`.

Comment: @Wieland that would have shown nothing. Perhaps `ls -d ~`

Comment: Quote the quotes, like `"'~'"`. Use `rm -i ???` to match all names with 3 chars and interactively choose y or n for each one. `ls` will report names inside quotes if it thinks they contain suspect characters -- the name may really be just `~`. Use `find . -name '~'` -- it should not treat it as HOME.

Comment: learning the hard way.. you can always use `find` to list files, it has lot of search and exclude options (size date permissions etc) once only desired file is printed, add `-delete` flag